# How to remove 4000 instance in WEKA evenly spread across class attribute?

Tags: weka

So I'm trying to move 4000 instances from my data set (there is 12660 instances with 10 values of class attribute)

When I use the `Remove Percentage` filter  it take the first percentage of instances. I'd like to remove instances equally across the class attributes.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Filter Supervised Instance Resample.